# How to identify back button event in Xamarin cross-platform (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, back

Is there any way to know when the '**back**' button event on the 'Android phone' is pressed? I'd like to exit the game and add few functionality to it when this button is pressed in Xamarin.Forms.
I googled a bit regarding this, but I got articles regarding Xamarin.Android Back button but not for Xamarin.Forms.
As I am relatively new to Xamarin.Forms, please help me out

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    //base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

Same thing I want in Xamarin.Forms. Need some assistance, guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept Navigation Bar Back Button Clicked in Xamarin Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696595/how-to-intercept-navigation-bar-back-button-clicked-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: You can use OnBackPressed on MainActivity.cs for Android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) by "Xamarin Cross Platform", there is a [`OnBackButtonPressed`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed()/) event that you can use. As seen on that documentation:

> Event that is raised when the hardware back button is pressed. This
>   event is not raised on iOS.

Simply override this event on your `NavigationPage` and you're ready to go:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    // Do your magic here
    return true;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: `return true` to prevent back, `return false` to just do something before going back.

Answer (score 1):

In my xamarin forms app you need to find the NavigationStack of the current Page if you are using master page:

```
public bool DoBack
    {
        get
        {
            MasterDetailPage mainPage = App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;

            if (mainPage != null)
            {    
                bool doBack = mainPage.Detail.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1 || mainPage.IsPresented;

                //top level of page and the Master menu isn't showing
                if (!doBack)
                {
                    // don't exit the app only show the Master menu page
                    mainPage.IsPresented = true;
                    return false; 
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }                    
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```