# How to intercept Navigation Bar Back Button Clicked Prism Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

Basically Its the same question from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696595/how-to-intercept-navigation-bar-back-button-clicked-in-xamarin-forms) but the solution dosen't work for Prism MVVM because the `OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)` in the `MainActivity` never get raised.
 For the hardware button I'm using on that page:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    return !PageUtilities.CanNavigate(this, null);
}
```

Comment: That just shows me how many people are using Prism :-) if nobody replies

Comment: @YuriS not according to this link https://dotnet.libhunt.com/project/mvvmcross/vs/prism?rel=cmp-cat

Comment: The question  needs more details on what have been done, OnBackButtonPressed is event and not a delegate command which is used in Prism MVVM. Got to know the details

Comment: I tried this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696595/how-to-intercept-navigation-bar-back-button-clicked-in-xamarin-forms#answer-31754517

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here   https://xamarindevelopervietnam.wordpress.com/2016/11/19/how-to-handle-hardwaresoftware-back-button-from-viewmodel-in-xamarin-forms/
works well

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = !PageUtilities.CanNavigate(this, null);
   base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

Cancel the event when navigation neeeds to be stopped

Comment: the base class has no 'OnBackPress' to override where did you find that?

Comment: you can use from NavigationPage



public class MyNavigationPage : NavigationPage
 {
  public override void OnBackPressed()
  {
   if(App.Instance.DoBack)
   {
    base.OnBackPressed();
   }
  }

  public bool DoBack
  {
   get
   {
    NavigationPage mainPage = MainPage as NavigationPage;
    if (mainPage != null)
    {
     return mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1;
    }
    return true;                
   }
  }
 }

Comment: the problem is that the `OnBackButtonPressed` only gets executed when the hardware button is pressed - this is a  xamarin issue - that's why i linked the stack overflow thread that discusses this issue and was looking for solution when using prism

Answer (score -3):

I guess there is no straight or single answer to this.
Based on your requirement you must need to provide MVVM implementation.

Latest Prism Library update has the **OnNavigatedFrom** method (you'll require to override by implementing INavigationAware interface)

```
    public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
     // here is the place you would require to handle the Back button event, 
     // this is fired every-time, user tries to leave the view. 
    }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
     // fired upon view load
    }
```

You may require a static (boolean or something) variable to keep a check if the user is leaving the view and optionally display a message or invalidate the action.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

N Baua

Comment: the `OnNavigatedFrom` is being executed once the page is popped from the stack

Comment: Your question is then not clearly stating what you've done so far, my answer is based on the for Prism MVVM guide-lines. Open-up and post some more information on what you've done so far, may be then anyone can help you.